# Whats the full name of HMOBA?

Tags: identification

I'm doing some statisitcal research and I have come across an acronym for a chemical. I have tried googling it but it comes up with very little and I can't find the name. 
I only have **HMOBA**. Can anyone tell me what this stands for?

Comment: there is this image from a chinese journal : http://www.jcscp.org/article/2016/1005-4537/1005-4537-36-5-389/img_6.png

Comment: You should specify where you came across the acronym. Gilleain has a reasonable answer, but it could also be the HMOBA from this [patent](http://www.google.ch/patents/US20040048343) which is  N-(2-hydroxy-3-methyl-1-oxobutyl)-β-alanine or from this [other patent](http://google.jp/patents/WO2009141384A2?cl=en) which mentions 3-hydroxy-4-methoxybenzylamine.

Comment: It might be possible to figure it out from the context of where you are seeing this. As it stands, there is not enough information to answer unambiguously.